# virtually boot my rpi-disk in mac env

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, boot, virtualization

I have an SSD disk with Raspbian on it. When I plug it into my MAC it only shows the boot partition (not the filesystem that you get once booted into the actual raspbian).

Is there a simple way to boot into this disk from my mac using a virtual machine? Or do I have to physically plug it into a raspberry machine to access the contents?

Comment: The macOS doesn’t support ext4 filesystems, but any Linux system should be able to read it.

Comment: Something like https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/138993/148797 you may need to create an image of the disk instead of the /dev/diskN device